# Capistrano giving error from old release. ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn

I have  deployed my app using `capistrano` on `AWS`, with `nginx` and `unicorn`. When I open my home page, its empty. This is my `unicorn` log

```
Started GET "/" for 111.111.111.111 at 2014-03-10 12:50:02 +0000
Processing by StaticController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 236ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template static/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/deployer/apps/my-app/releases/20140310084512/app/views"
  * "/home/deployer/apps/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.8/app/views"
  * "/home/deployer/apps/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/glimpse-redis-1.1.0/app/views"
  * "/home/deployer/apps/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/glimpse-git-1.0.1/app/views"
  * "/home/deployer/apps/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/glimpse-0.0.5/app/views"
  * "/home/deployer/apps/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"
  * "/home/deployer/apps/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.3/app/views"
  * "/home/deployer/apps/my-app/releases/20140310124541"
  * "/"
):
  app/controllers/static_controller.rb:8:in `index'
```

My latest release is `20140310124541`, but the missing template error is coming from a previous release `20140310084512`. What could be the issue. The `current` folder symlink is created properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to make sure that you restart nginx/unicorn.  Once a program looks up a folder/file in symlink, it will point to the target. So, when capistrano points current to the latest release, nginx still is looking at old target which is now most likely deleted.

Make sure you have restart taks setup as shown here: https://github.com/sosedoff/capistrano-unicorn

Comment: Hi akshah, thank for your answer. I had already restarted nginx and unicorn, but no luck.

Comment: The problem is definitely that nginx/unicorn is looking at the wrong folder.  Either your config for unicorn is not looking at current folder or you are not restarting after symlink is updated.  Perhaps, restart happens before symlink is set.  What is your restart task & its before/after command look like?

Comment: Yes the problem was with restart. For some weird reason, restart command did not work. But when I did stop and start, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Same thing for me, the regular deploy did not work, but manually stoping and then starting the server fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`--trace` flag gave me more info. In my case a gem was missing and I did not spot the error. `passenger` was the gem.

Answer (score 0):

[akshah123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1681125/akshah123)'s solution is the answer, I wanted to share my observations if that may help others.

in the deploy/your_environment.rb (ex: `deploy/staging.rb`) or `deploy.rb` you can add:

```
after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'for resetting symlinks that are getting stuck in the normal deploy process'
  task :restart do
    invoke 'unicorn:reload'
  end
end
```

Depending on how your Capistrano is setup you may see the following:

```
Skipping task `unicorn:start'.
Capistrano tasks may only be invoked once. Since task `unicorn:start' was previously invoked, invoke("unicorn:start") at /Users/newman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/capistrano3-unicorn-0.2.1/lib/capistrano3/tasks/unicorn.rake:49 will be skipped.
If you really meant to run this task again, use invoke!("unicorn:start")
THIS BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE IN A FUTURE VERSION OF CAPISTRANO. Please join the conversation here if this affects you.
```

This should be okay in most cases, as the redundancy is being handled and the desired result of remapping the symlinks occurs. The suggested fix from the message likely can't /doesn't need to be implemented in this case, as we are implicitly calling `unicorn:start` from calling `unicorn:reload`, in other words: `invoke! unicorn:reload` does not handle / prevent  this message from rendering.